# jquery select multiple options show and hide input type number with placeholder

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

```
<div class="form-group"><label for="unit_of">Unit of Measure</label>
<select class="form-control-sm selectpicker" multiple="multiple" id="unit_of" name="unit_of[]" data-selected-text-format="count">
<?php $sql = "select * from unit_of";
$res = mysqli_query($db_handle, $sql);
while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$unit_of = $list['unit_of'];
?>
<option><?= $unit_of; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control-sm" id="rates" name="rates" >
<input type="text" class="form-control-sm" id="rates1" name="rates1" style="display:none">
<input type="text" class="form-control-sm" id="rates2" name="rates2" style="display:none">
```

In the dropdown
Per Minute
Per Page,
Per Hour,
Per Day,
Per Month,
Per Item,
Per Contract,
Others

I want onchange multiple select hide and show input types number e.g.(name="per_page") e.g.("Enter Rate Per Page") for three input type

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there are 2 questions here really:

**How to restrict a multiple select to a max of 3 selections?**

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but my recommendation would be to validate this right before the form is submitted. If you're using a form validation library, try adding the code in there. If not, then you can add a custom submit event handler that will validate the selections. Maybe something like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    var selectionCount = $("#unit_of option:selected").length;
    if (selectionCount > 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You may only select up to 3 options.");
    }
});
```

**How to add a placeholder to the multiple select?**

You can add a placeholder option just before the PHP code adds the other options, like so:

```
<select class="form-control-sm selectpicker" multiple="multiple" id="unit_of" 
name="unit_of[]" data-selected-text-format="count">
<option value="">Enter Rate Per Page</option>
<?php $sql = "select * from unit_of";
$res = mysqli_query($db_handle, $sql);
while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$unit_of = $list['unit_of'];
?>
<option><?= $unit_of; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Of course, with this approach, you'll need to add extra validation code to make sure that the placeholder option is not one of the selected options.

Comment: Thank you but I want onchage options input type hide or show and input type name="per_page_rate" for three input type

Comment: I still don't understand. Maybe provide an example or 2?